# Restore session by spring social

Tags: android, spring, social-networking

I'am new in spring social framework and faced on difficult problem. Need to restore sessions with socials (Twitter, LinkedIn) by their tokens. But don't know how exactly.
I use the way f.e LinkedIn:

```
  AccessGrant accessGrant = new AccessGrant(socialTokenData.getAuthToken());
  final Connection<LinkedIn> connection = BaseApplication.linkedInConnectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
```

but second line throws exception:
org.springframework.social.NotAuthorizedException: Invalid access token.
Someone, please, help me to restore session.
After success login to social I save Token and  I take it from sharedPreference when app starts again... Googling not helps.